# Map top results from a query wth Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble putting some things together. I can make a php page that will display results from a mysql database and I can get addresses to map with google, but I can't seem to put both of them together.

What I am trying to do is to map the first 2 or 3 results for a database search. I just can't seem to pass in the address from the results into the geocoder. I've tried a few different ways but I really don't know where to start and a lot of what I am reading is over my head. (Javascript is NOT something I've really worked with much before.)

I've got the code I have below. I know it is missing some elements so therefore does not work. It would be great if someone could help me out and show me how to pass my values in properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.174208, -84.481842);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}


function codeAddress() {
    //How do I get these addresses from the query?
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var address2 = document.getElementById("address2").value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address2}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });


    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<?php
//Include Function- positive this is fine.
include ('../includes/dbCon.php');
echo "Page Header Stuff<br><br>";
$query= "SELECT full_addr from address_lst limit 2";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
echo "<div>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['addr'];
}
?>
<input type="button" value="Map These!" onclick="codeAddress()">
</div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 680px; height: 480px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create elements(e.g. input's) with the required ID's(address & address2) and the desired values:

```
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<input id="address'.((!!$i++)? $i : '').'" 
                 value="'.htmlentities($row['addr']).'" />';
}
```

Comment: I can't up vote your answer since I am so new but this is exactly what this newbie needed. I've never used htmlentities() before and did not know to even google this. Just knowing where to start looking helps tremendously! Danke Schön!